# KnockoutJS validationMessage property location

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I cannot find the `validationMessage` property of an observable so that I can bind it on the 'visible' binding. I need to check if this property is null so that there is a condition to set the display-none to true for a certain div.

I have extended the observable to have some validations and display the validation message when there is a message to display but hide the div when there is no validation message.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onlyIf` option to determine when the validation should be ignored (and thus no message displayed):

```
self.postalCode.extend({
    required: {
        message: "Postal Code is required",
        onlyIf: function() {
            return self.noPostalCode() === false;
        }
    }
});
```

See this page: https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Conditional-Validation-with-onlyIf-parameter